# Default Linear Discriminant Analysis solver in R MASS

Tags: r, scikit-learn

What's the default solver of Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) in R MASS? For example when running something along the lines

```
mylda <- lda(dep~ind1+ind2+ind3)
```

[R MASS docs on LDA](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/lda.html) are not really clear. There is a mention of parameter `method`, which can be "momentum" or "mle" (maximum likelihood estimation), but can't see how this relates to scikit-learn, where [scikit-learn API docs on LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis) clearly state that the following can be uses for the solver: Singular value decomposition ("svd"), Least squares ("lsqr"), or Eigenvalue decomposition ("eigen").

Comment: Look at the source code of `MASS:::lda.default`. I see calls to `svd` there.

Comment: Thanks. Helpful reminder of RTS.